# Add life every N hours

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement mechanism that will be add one life to `UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lifes")` every 4 hours even if app was closed and notify user about it.

About notifications i read articles, it will not be hard. But how increase life number value if i didn't be in game for 12 hours. I should get `+3` lifes when back.

Comment: you can notify the user via local notification in every 4 hours (annoying, but...), and you can add all lives at once when the application opens again, calculating how many hours has spend since last time the app was open, and you can do a `lives += hours / 4` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an event when the game is paused (UIApplicationWillResignActive) so you can write down in user defaults what time it was. You get an event when the game resumes (UIApplicationDidBecomeActive) so you can check to see what time it is and how many hours have elapsed since you became inactive.

Comment: Though I respect the fact that the answer you mentioned above works but the suggested solution can be devastating and might lead to disaster as you are completely dependent on the device local time. What if user puts the app to background and changes the time by 24 hours and launches the app again u will end up adding +6 life which is wrong, rather what should be the approach is to every time you launch the app ask the server associated the time elapsed and keep notifying server about the time stamp at a regular interval when in foreground :) just like chat apps does :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari If that happens you can receive the day-changed notification from NSCalendar and compensate accordingly.

Comment: @arti : notifying user after every 4 hours as one of the answer suggested will only lead user to uninstall your app, so notifying user after every four hours drop the idea :) if you want to achieve it at any cost you can't relay on device local time stamps it is vulnerable, rather you could depend on APNS or GCM push notification.

Comment: According to the question, the user should be informed every 4 hours.

Comment: @matt : I was giving just an example what if user changes the time by 4 hours and date won't change then ?? Basically all am trying to say is completely relaying on local device time stamp can be dangerous :)

Comment: the main question: how i can correct restore user lifes

Comment: using the local timestamp is probably more than enough for your task. If the users realise there's an exploit you can fix that later on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if the app is "closed".

The only way to achieve this behaviour is to use Push Notifications (pushed by your server, not the app).

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) Apple documentation.

---

My opinion is, that the user will delete your app, as she will get disturbed by too frequent notifications.